# Intersection of Regular Open is Regular Open

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Below is a question and my attempted solution. I saw this question before but someone took a more "pointwise" approach, however, I did not think such approach was needed. Therefore, I am wondering if the following proof/solution is correct.

Let $U$ and $V$ be Regular Open, i.e. $U = \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(U)$ and
$V = \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(V)$. Show that the intersection of $U$ and $V$ is Regular Open, i.e. $U \cap V = \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(U \cap V)$.

(my) **Solution:** For any sets $U$ and $V$ we have that
$\operatorname{cl}(U \cap V) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(U) \cap \operatorname{cl}(V)$. By monotonicity of interior we have
$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(U \cap V) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(U) \cap \operatorname{cl}(V))$. Since intersections are preserved with respect to interior we have that
$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(U \cap V) \subseteq \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(U) \cap \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(V)$. Since $U$ and $V$ are Regular Open we have that the following holds:

$$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(U \cap V) \subseteq U \cap V. \quad (i)$$

For the other inclusion, notice that for any sets $U$ and $V$ we have that $U \cap V \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(U \cap V) \quad (*)$. Since $U$ and $V$ are Regular Open, they are open, hence, $U \cap V$ is open. Therefore, we can write $U \cap V = \operatorname{int}(U \cap V)$. By $(*)$ we have that
$U \cap V \subseteq \operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(U \cap V))$. Therefore, we can write
$$U \cap V \subseteq \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(U \cap V). \quad (ii)$$

By both $(i)$ and $(ii)$ the following holds
$$U \cap V = \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(U \cap V),$$
as desired.

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: For the 2nd inclusion, observe that $W=U\cap V$ is open because $U$ and $V$ are open. So $\text { int cl } W\supseteq \text { int } W=W.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the proof is fine.

Indeed only one inclusion uses the fact that $U$ and $V$ are themselves regular open.

My summarised argument: as $U$ and $V$ are regular open

$$U \cap V = \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl} U \cap \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl} V\tag{1}$$

and as interior respects $\cap$ (just as closure respects $\cup$) while for closure we have $\operatorname{cl}( A \cap B) \subseteq \operatorname{cl} A \cap \operatorname{cl} B$ for all $A,B$ (the right hand side is closed and contains $A \cap B$ so also its closure) we get:

$$ U \cap V = \operatorname{int}( \operatorname{cl} U \cap \operatorname{cl} V) \supseteq \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl}(U \cap V)\tag{2}$$

As $U \cap V$ is open and a subset of $\operatorname{cl}( U \cap V)$ trivially:

$$U \cap V \subseteq \operatorname{int} \operatorname{cl}(U \cap V)\tag{3}$$

and $(2)$ and $(3)$ combined show the result.